# Hibernate lazy relations are fetched n+1 without properties being called - Kotlin

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, kotlin

I am using hibernate and doing a simple query to select all of a given entity. I only want the entity and not its relations. However hibernate does fetch the relations and the relations of the relations, in a n+1 manner.

It's a Spring Boot application and written in Kotlin.

The relations are annotated with FetchType.LAZY and the query i'm doing looks like so:

```
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Apartment a")
    .resultList
```

This is the only code that i am calling and i do NOT even return the results from the controller, so it is not some serialization library that calls the lazy properties.

These are the entities:

```
@Entity
class Apartment(
        @Id
        private val id: String,
        private val heading: String,
        @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
        private val building: Building
)

@Entity
class Building(
        @Id
        private val id: String,
        private val heading: String,
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private val owner: User
)

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
class User(
        @Id
        private val id: String,
        private val email: String
)
```

I have turned on hibernate query logging, and when i run the query above it looks like:

```
Fetch all apartments
Fetch buildings for apartment 1
Fetch users for building 1
fetch buildings for apartment 2
fetch users for building 2
....
```

I have created a git repository that reproduces the problem: https://github.com/Herlevsen/hibernate-lazy-fetch-repoduction

It comes setup with a docker-compose file that launches a postgres database, and the application automatically creates the schema and creates some dummy data on startup. So it's fairly easy to get up and running.

I'm really hoping someone can tell me what's going on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `open` the entity classes. Hibernate requires `open` classes to create proxies to support  `LAZY` - `ManyToOne` fields:

```
@Entity
open class Apartment(
    @Id
    private val id: String,
    private val heading: String,
    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    private val building: Building
)

@Entity
open class Building(
    @Id
    private val id: String,
    private val heading: String,
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private val owner: User
)

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
open class User(
    @Id
    private val id: String,
    private val email: String
)
```

You can also use the [`all-open`-Plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#all-open-compiler-plugin).

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution :-) I tried using the all-open plugin and configured it with Hibernates @Entity annotation. However, my code failed to compile because i use private setters for most of my properties. Do you know if there's a way around this?

Comment: Could you provide the source code with the private setters and the compilation error message?

Comment: I have updated the repository, specifically the Apartment class. The error is now the following: ...../demo/src/main/kotlin/com/example/demo/Apartment.kt: (17, 17): Private setters are not allowed for open properties. The error does make sense to me. However i would like to keep my setters private, when the properties are not supposed to be mutated from the outside. So if it was possible to remove private from the setter at build time via a plugin. That way my own code, can not call the setter, but hibernate would still be able to proxy the setter. Have you heard of such a plugin? :-) Thanks!

Comment: You could use `internal` instead of `private`. `internal` means , it is visible everywhere in the same module/file (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html). As long as you put each entity in one file, it means the same as `private`.